# GitLab CI - only: changes: use case

Tags: build, gitlab-ci, monorepo

In a monorepo micro-services architecture, with one service per folder, I'm trying to use the new CI feature `refs: changes`.

My pipeline consists of building docker image in each folders (=service), then if everything is green, 
it deploys each services to AWS.

Here is a preview of what it looks like:

[image: CI Pipeline]

In the image, we see that the job `api-build` failed. It means that the `deploy` jobs will not run (assume that `!` means skipped).

The issue in the api was located in the api folder. So after fixing it and pushing the fix, only the api jobs will run. This is expected because of:

```
    only:
        refs:
            - release
            - uat
        changes:
            - "api/**/*"
            - "*"
```

Which gives me:

[image]

The other services have been skipped in the previous pipeline and now are not deployed because they contain no change.

Now the issue/question: is this a good approach for this kind of monorepo? How do I handle that?

I've 24+ services and if they trigger a job each time without changes, it will slow down the deployment (and it's a waist of resource).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good candidate for the [`needs` functionality](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needs). Once the build for `srv[1-3]` is finished, they can be deployed immediately.

```
srv1-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  needs:
    - job: srv1-build
      artifacts: true
```